# Accessibility: JAWS doesn't pronounce aria-live polite or assertive for *ngIf

Tags: javascript, html, angular, accessibility, aria-live

I'm using Angular, and **every time** when `isVisible` from the code below becomes *true* the html code below gets rendered on the page.

```
<div *ngIf="isVisible">
  <span aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">Read this new text</span>
</div>
```

Every time it gets rendered (can be removed and added several times based on behavior), I need JAWS to pronounce the text in the span: `Read this new text`.
For that purpose I tried to use aria-live="polite" (doesn't pronounce) and even aria-live="assertive" and even aria-live="assertive" with aria-atomic="true" based on this [Aria-live region is not reading out updates when an element is removed on chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734798) question.

How to make it work?
Used: JAWS, Google Chrome.

Comment: Adding or removing live regions is not working well, you should manipulate only the contents of such a region. Can you try `<div aria-live="assertive"><span *ngIf="isVisible">…`? Why is there a tabindex?

Comment: @Andy, that should be an answer. Thank you. And right, tabindex was not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding or removing live regions is not working well, you should manipulate only the contents of such a region.

```
<div aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <span *ngIf="isVisible">Read this new text</span>
</div>
```

Whether `assertive` is the right choice should be very carefully considered. It is quite disruptive for the user. `polite` is the better choice most of the time.

> When regions are specified as assertive, assistive technologies will immediately notify the user, and could potentially clear the speech queue of previous updates.

– [ARIA on `aria-live`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-live)

Another general advise is that the information that gets announced needs to be easily accessible on the user’s terms as well, should they have missed it or not understood. The error message for a field should be announced via an alert, but also be bound to the input field, to be read every time the user focuses the field.

Comment: Good answer but I would recommend `polite` instead of `assertive`.  It should be rare that `assertive` is ever needed.  I know the OP used `assertive` so you were just using their code sample.

Comment: I added some text to the answer, does that meet your concerns?